# How to get incorrect CSS property value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get original value of a CSS property, even if the value is incorrect.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('value');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
el.insertAdjacentText('afterbegin', style.getPropertyValue('color'));
```

```css
#value {
 color: foo;
}
```

```html
<p>
 Property <code>color</code> value (should be <em>foo</em>): <code id="value"></code>
</p>
```

In the code above I used `foo` as a value of `color` property, which obviously is incorrect — there's no color with that name, nor is it accepted color format. However, when I read that value in JavaScript, I get `rgb(0, 0, 0)` instead of `foo`.

I want to get original value, as it appears in stylesheet. How can I achieve that?

http://codepen.io/xerif/pen/NpqKBO/

Comment: if the property value is invalid it won't be set by the browser rendering engine and is therefore not accessible in the dom

Comment: why do you even want this ? what is the big goal behind it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate issues

The first is that there are numerous different formats to set colors but browsers will only return one format for `getComputedStyle` .The format returned may not even be consistent cross browser. For example one browser might return `rgb` and another `rgba`

The other is that when an invalid value is provided in a css rule  it won't be set by the browser rendering engine and therefore is not accessible in the dom.

What you are asking can't be done